# Can we imply regualr expression for a custom field in Azure Dev Ops custom template

Tags: azure, azure-devops

Can you please help me to confirm if we can implement below requiement for Azure Dev Ops custom field ?

We have a requirement to add field with work item template which can take multiple integer values separated by a delimiter (, or space or new line)
It should not allow users to enter values other than integer or delimeter for that field.

Thanks,
Rahul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That available only in old Azure DevOps On-premises XML process models: [Apply pattern matching to a string field](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/xml/apply-pattern-matching-to-string-field?view=azure-devops-2020&viewFallbackFrom=azure-devops). The modern Inherited process does not contain such rules: [Add a rule to a work item type (Inheritance process)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/custom-rules?view=azure-devops).